# Bash: Script Calling Gnome Terminal Leads To Child Process Error?

Tags: bash, terminal, xterm, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to have a script open a new terminal window, and then call another script in that terminal.

I'm getting the error:

> There was an error creating the child process for this terminal

I believe it has something to do with the calling script trying to run the child processes.

I've tried the --x option in gnome-terminal.  It's not working.
I'm sure there is a way to tell Terminal to execute commands in the new Terminal.  I just can't seem to find it in the documentation anywhere.

Anyone run into this and have a fix?

**Ref problem code:  Line 57, 58:**

```
sudo gnome-terminal -x --window --wait --tab --active --title="$1" --geometry=120X60 \
--working-directory="$code_directory"  --command "$file_path"
```

Script in full context:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Runs last modified script in new Terminal window tab in dev qube.

# Global vars
qube_name='dev'
code_directory='/home/user/Documents/'
last_modified='' # Last modified file in code directory.
file_path='' # Full file path of last modified file.


# Gets the last modified file in the code directory.
get_filename(){
    cd "$code_directory"
     last_modified=$(ls -t | head -n1)
    echo "$last_modified"
}


# Returns full file path.
get_full_path(){
    # $1=filename
    export file_path="$code_directory$1"
    echo "$file_path"
}


# Stops script if last modified file is this one.
check_filename(){
    # $1=file path
    # Guard clause to prevent recursive call.
    if [ "$1" == 'run_last_modified.sh' ]; then
        msg='Last modified file is run_last_modified.sh.
            Stopping execution...'
        notify-send "$msg";echo "$msg"
        exit
    fi
    echo "$1"
}

# Makes file executable if it isn't already.
make_executable(){
    #$1=file_path
    msg="Making $file_path executable..."
    echo "$msg"
    sudo chmod +x "$1"
    echo "$1"
}

# Opens a new terminal window and runs the file.
run_in_terminal(){
    #$1=file_path
    msg="Running $1 in $qube_name Terminal..."
    notify-send "$msg";echo "$msg"

    # -x option deprecated.  

    sudo gnome-terminal -x --window --wait --tab --active --title="$1" --geometry=120X60 \
    --working-directory="$code_directory"  --command "$file_path"

    # For dom0
    # qvm-run "$qube_name gnome-terminal -e $file_path"
}

run(){
    # Pipeline
    last_modified=$(get_filename)
    file_path=$(get_full_path)
    check_filename "$file_path"
    make_executable "$file_path" 
    run_in_terminal "$file_path"
}

run

################## TESTS #################
# Note to self: Comment out run ^^^ before running tests.

tests(){
    # get filename test.
    last_modified=$(get_filename)
    msg="Last modified: $last_modified"
    notify-send "$msg";echo "$msg"

    # get filepath test.
    file_path=$(get_full_path "$last_modified")
    msg="File path: $file_path"
    notify-send "$msg";echo "$msg"

    # Check filename test.
    # last_modified='run_last_modified.sh'
    # check_filename # Should stop execution.

    # Make executable tests.
    make_executable "$file_path"

}

# tests
```

Comment: I'd suggest running the script with trace logging, as in `bash -x your_script` (or putting `set -x` somewhere near the top of the script); that way you can see the exact `gnome-terminal` command it's running and experiment with that command to find a variant that works as you intend.

Comment: BTW, while it doesn't appear to be the problem you're running into right now (it would be a different error message), it's not unusual for commands run with `sudo` to be unable to connect to the X server due to environment variables like Xauthority not being propagated. If you want your program to continue to work with newer distros with tighter security, I would suggest doing privilege escalation _after_ the terminal starts rather than before; that also reduces the chances of an attack against the terminal itself allowing direct access to root.

Comment: Requiring a separate terminal is a common beginner request but often eventually a bad idea. Perhaps you can run a background process with output to a file, which you can examine when you need to from any available terminal.

Comment: (see https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-27135 as an example of an attack against the terminal itself as referenced above)

Comment: ...also, I do agree with tripleee as a matter of good practice -- logging to a file (the system journal, etc) is much more flexible than logging to a terminal; the terminal approach _only_ works with human consumers, whereas in real-world systems it's generally desirable to be able to put automation in place between the humans and where the work happens.

Comment: Another portability node: Use `=`, not `==`, for string comparisons in `[`/`test`. See the relevant POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html -- support for `=` is mandated, whereas `==` is not specified at all.

Comment: Also, see [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for better-practice guidance for finding the newest or oldest file in a directory; [`ls` is unreliable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: (another thing -- and http://shellcheck.net/ will identify this automatically -- is that it's generally wise to always check whether `cd` succeeds in your script; `cd ... || exit` will ensure the script aborts if the `cd` fails, instead of running code in a directory other than the intended location).

Comment: @tripleee, I'm trying to streamline the coding/testing cycle:  A hotkey that runs a script that. saves->launches terminal->runs last saved file.  Perhaps I'm using the wrong approach.  (I could not get Vscode to do it with a hotkey.  I find it crazy that there's not a simple hotkey to do it built in? I'm not sure how I would debug with an output file, as some scripts require user inputs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Thanks for the "set -x" tip.

Comment: Requiring interactive I/O is a separate atnipattern to avoid. You want to at least offer an option to specify arguments etc one the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-x` and `--command` are incorrect/obsolete options, try this :

```
sudo gnome-terminal --window --wait --tab --active --geometry=120X60 \
    --title="$1" --working-directory="$code_directory" -- "$file_path"
```

To keep the terminal window open :

```
sudo gnome-terminal --window --wait --tab --active --geometry=120X60 \
    --title="$1" --working-directory="$code_directory"\
    -- bash -c "$file_path; exec bash"
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Except it's closing the terminal window after the called script completes.  Do you know of a flag that would keep the terminal window open?

Comment: Nice.  Works perfectly now.

Comment: Running a terminal with `sudo` seems like a very acutely terrible idea. If you need to run a privileged shell *inside* the terminal, do that instead.

Comment: @tripleee Can you explain to OP what's wrong with the use of sudo ?

Comment: Basic security hygiene; user GUI code should not run privileged. Also, it's probably complicating matters because `root` should not have access to your `$DISPLAY`

Comment: OP would still not understand the why of "should not".

Comment: How can I execute multi command? For example I want to execute "cd /myhome/" and  then "make" then "something" in gnome-terminal .

Comment: @Carter You can do `bash -c "cd ...; make; something; exec bash"`